# Does the Battery light mean Low Oil?

Tags: battery, warning-light, low-oil

My battery light came on, my car seemed to lose power and cut off. Today I was told it was because the oil was low in the car so the computer was shutting down the engine to keep it from causing more problems. Is this correct?

Answer (score 1):

If battery light came and car was still running, I don't think it's because of low oil. You can check the oil and see for yourself. But if oil is low you have a oil light that will come on, not the battery one. Indeed some cars shut off when oil level is low, but I don't think that's the case.

Comment: thanks to @mike65535 for the edit i was still in bed when i wrote it.

Comment: Just about every car has a "low oil pressure" light. But far fewer cars have a "low oil" light that indicates oil level. Because we don't know what car the OP has, we don't know if she's talking about a low oil _pressure_ indication or a low oil _quantity_ indication.

Comment: The battery light illuminating is more likely to indicate a problem with the cars charging circuit. If the battery isn't charging, the ignition will discharge the battery and eventually die altogether.